# split list elements iteratively

Tags: python, list, split

I want to split a list `names` element. More precicely i only want to split the strings with `Oscar Muller`

```
names = ['Oscar Muller Some other Name', 'Oscar Muller', 'Peter Pan']
expected_names = ['Oscar Muller', 'Some other Name', 'Oscar Muller', 'Peter Pan']
```

---

```
d = "Oscar Muller "
for line in names:
    s = [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
```

That didnt do anything.

`[list(filter(None, re.split(r'Oscar\sMuller\s', i))) for i in names]`

didnt do anything either.

```
d1 = re.compile(r"Oscar\sMuller\s")
d = d1.search(names)
for line in names:
    if d:
        s = [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
```

but it caused issues with input `.split()`. Error: `TypeError: must be str or None, not re.Pattern`. So i changed it to process each list element.

```
d1 = re.compile(r"Oscar\sMuller\s")
d = list(filter(d1.match, names))
for line in names:
    if d:
        s = [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
```

But it didnt work either, returning `TypeError: must be str or None, not list`

**Question**: What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) for the regex split method. It must be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what you need to do is generate 1 or 2 item sublists for each item in the original list, and then flatten the list into a single iterable.

A couple ways you could do this. You could use a generator function, or some clever use of `itertools`

```
import re

def my_generator(names):
    for name in names:
        sublist = re.split(r"(?<=Oscar Muller) ", name)
        yield from sublist

names = ['Oscar Muller Some other Name', 'Oscar Muller', 'Peter Pan']
expected_names = list(my_generator(names))
```

Or you could one-liner it with `itertools`:

```
import itertools
import re

names = ['Oscar Muller Some other Name', 'Oscar Muller', 'Peter Pan']
expected_names = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.split(r"(?<=Oscar Muller) ", s) for s in names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension to make it one line:

```
import re
[j for i in [re.split(r"(?<=Oscar Muller)", k) for k in names] for j in i if j]
```